# Loading all the content before initializing the overlay

Tags: jquery, fancybox, preload

Hey :) I have a fancybox with holds inline content and generated content by JavaScript. Ofcourse the inline content loads a lot faster and the javascript take s a while. can i actually make the fancybox load in the background and just hide it, and then display it after all the javascript is loaded? Basically preload all the content, then open it.. without really destroying user experience..

My Setup is like this:

```
<div class="popupContent" style="display: none;">

  <div id="something_text"> bla bla bla </div>

  <div id="something_js_generated">
      <script> </script>
  </div>

</div
```

And my javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    type: 'inline',
                    href : '.popupContent',              
                }
            ], {
                closeClick: false,
                fitToView: true,
                autoResize: true,
                closeBtn: false,
                hideOnContentClick: true,
                hideOnOverlayClick: false,
                autoSize: true,
                openSpeed: 150,
                modal: true,
                padding : 0
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code that opens the fancybox in some function than call it from the javascript after it generates your "something".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopup() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    type: 'inline',
                    href : '.popupContent',              
                }
            ], {
                closeClick: false,
                fitToView: true,
                autoResize: true,
                closeBtn: false,
                hideOnContentClick: true,
                hideOnOverlayClick: false,
                autoSize: true,
                openSpeed: 150,
                modal: true,
                padding : 0
            });
        });

 </script>

<div id="something_js_generated">
      <script> 
      //generate something
      openPopup();
      </script>
</div>
```

Or maybe your generating code can trigger some event when it's done. Than you can bind the opening function to the event. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $( document).on( "myCustomEventsPrefix:OpenPopup",function(){
              $.fancybox.open(
                 //....
               );
         });

     </script>

    <div id="something_js_generated">
          <script> 
          //generate something
          $(document).trigger( "myCustomEventsPrefix:OpenPopup");
          </script>
    </div>
```